# Can't seem to get query to work?

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-insert

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

session_start();

include ('connect.php');

if(!empty($_POST['budgetbox']))
{
    $budgetboxvar = $_POST['budgetbox'];

    $sql="INSERT INTO users WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['usernamebox']."'(budget) VALUES ('$budgetboxvar')";


    mysqli_query($db,$sql); 


} 
?>
```

Does anyone have an idea why the code above doesn't work ? It seems like the code works if I leave the code below out. I'm sorry but I can't seem to figure out how this is not correct ? I'm not getting any error messages either.

When I take out the `WHEN username is SESSION usernamebox` part out.. the query does input into my database, only not in the field of a logged in user..

I tried to echo something if the query succeeded but it doesn't show anything either.. Which means the query can't be executed (I think). Can't figure out why though(it's hard being a noob sometimes)

Thank you in advance, hope you can help !

Comment: It makes no sense to have a `WHERE` clause in `iNSERT`. This is for creating new rows, so why would it need to find a row that matches the username first?

Comment: If the query fails, you should use `echo mysqli_error($db)` to see the reason.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to add a new row, or do you want to change the budget for the user? `INSERT` is for adding new rows, `UPDATE` is for modifying an existing row.

Comment: im trying to add budget to the row of the username so yeah i guess i should tru to use update then.. thanks ill try again now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!empty($_POST['budgetbox']))
{

$query = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET budget=? WHERE username=?"); ///statements voorbereiden

$budgetboxvar = $_POST['budgetbox'];
$name = $_SESSION['usernamebox']; //var toekennen

$query->bind_param("ss", $budgetboxvar, $name);
$query->execute();
echo"Thank you for entering your budget!";  
}
```

And.. i changed the database column "budget" to VARCHAR64

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, something like this:

```
 $sql = "UPDATE users SET budget='".$budgetboxvar."' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['usernamebox'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the (quick even) reaction, really appreciate it.. Next error though... look:     You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''crack' at line 1

Comment: 'crack' is it the value of $budgetboxvar variable or value of $_SESSION['usernamebox'] ??

Comment: Sure.. could it be because its an integer ? My guess is that its not the problem... Cant be.. since it does input this int to the budget table without the session username.. Gonna upload it instantly !

Comment: Its the value of  $_SESSION['usernamebox']

Comment: Is there any row with 'username' = 'crack' ?

Comment: http://s18.postimg.org/mg2fqz7yx/stackoverflow_db_structure.png <- the db structure

Comment: Yes, there is a row where username = crack

Comment: I dont think that would work... see: http://s12.postimg.org/6rkgwsyv1/stack_tables_info.png      the query can be executed only it doesnt work with update yet and the session username.. Still want me to change it into varchar ?

Comment: OK, tell me, what is the value of $budgetboxvar variable?

Comment: <form action="budget.php" method="POST">
    <span style="color:black">My budget is:</span><input type="text" name="budgetbox"> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Add my budget">   
    </form>       hmmm i cant CTRL+k  this code ? strange... Anyway.. the value is anything the logged in user enters in this form.. as long as it is an int smaller or equal to 3 characters

Comment: mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die(mysql_error()); write it so.. let's see what kind of error is there..

Comment: mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die(mysql_error()); doesnt output any error message.. so i tried mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());    (mind mysqli instead of mysql) it outputs: Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\WPM 31 David Schol\Week 1 en 2\budget.php on line 17

Comment: Try to change from INT to VARCHAR and increase number of characters . . .

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem either.. somehow.. But i managed to work around the original code and tried something different AND this DOES seem to work. I did change the budget column in my database to VARCHAR64.

Comment: if(!empty($_POST['budgetbox']))
{
    
$query = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET budget=? WHERE username=?"); ///statements voorbereiden
    
$budgetboxvar = $_POST['budgetbox'];
$name = $_SESSION['usernamebox']; //var toekennen
    
$query->bind_param("ss", $budgetboxvar, $name);
$query->execute();
echo"Thank you for entering your budget!";  
}

Comment: Hmm ctrl+k doenst work in comments ?(sorry im kinda new here)